# Finding Unique values in a Dataset

Tags: python, sql

I have a dataset which is as follows:

```
Visitor ID    Page Id      TimeStamp
1             a            x1
2             b            x2
3             c            x3 
2             d            x4
```

Here are the rules of the data:

1). Consider this as a web data where a visitor visits the website and does some interaction. VID stand for Visitor Unique Id. Page Id is the ID of the page which he visited and Time stamp is the time of visit.

2). If the page refreshes then Time stamp will change and hence a new row will be created in the dataset with the same values of VID,Page Id but different value of Timestamp.

3). If the visitor clicks on other page both Timestamp and Page Id will change. Lets say he was on page 'a' first and then he goes to page 'b', so he will have another record in the dataset with same VID, but Page id now =b and Timestamp the new timestamp.

Problem:

I want to find out all unique VIDs who have visited a page 'b' AFTER visiting page 'a'. Please note that I would want it for a particular session or day.

Can someone help with both the sql and Pythonic way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select unique(visitor_id) from table_name where page_id="a" and visitor_id in (select unique(visitor_id) from table_name where page_id="b" and timestamp="any day");
```

Comment: I don't think this does whats intended. This would select all VIDs where paged is a and b. What I need is VIDs who have visited page b after visiting page a.

Answer (score 0):

The sql way would be:

```
select distinct(t1.vid) from my_table as t1 
inner join my_table as t2 on t1.vid = t2.vid
where t1.page_id = 'a' and t2.page_id='b' and t1.time < t2.time;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you (or others) started on the Pythonic part:

If you can, get your data into a NumPy [record array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) (e.g. using [numpy.genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)):

```
records = np.array([(1,'a',100),
                    (2,'a',100),
                    (1,'b',200),
                    (1,'a',300)],
                   dtype=dict(names=['vid','pid','time'],
                              formats=['i4','S1','i4']))
```

where the field 'time' is some comparable int/float/str or python [datetime.datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) instance. Actually `'x1'`,`'x2'` etc. would work, too. Then you can do stuff like

```
records_of_interest = records[records['time'] > 200]
```

I would then loop through the visitor IDs and see if their records match your criteria:

```
target_vids = []
vids = np.unique(records['vid'])
for vid in vids:
    # get the indices for the visitor's records
    ii = np.where(records['vid'] == vid)[0]
    # make sure they visited page 'b' at all
    if 'b' not in records[ii]['pid']:
        continue
    # check whether they visited 'a' before 'b' 
    lastvisit_b = np.where(records[ii]['pid'] == 'b')[0].max()
    firstvisit_a = np.where(records[ii]['pid'] == 'a')[0].min()
    if firstvisit_a < lastvisit_b:
        target_vids.append(vid)
```

`target_vids` now contains your desired visitor IDs.

Then again, there are also Python interfaces to SQL, which might reduce your problem to one language...